# php search a mysql string results

Tags: php, mysql

guys just a quick question. I have a string in a mysql row resembling this

`'google.co.nz, stackoverflow.com, facebook.com, grubber.co.nz'`

and so on... I would like to search all the rows in the table and check how many times  'facebook.com' shows up in all the rows that are like the ones above so to clarify

my rows look like this

```
-- id -- user -- likes 
   1      bob     facebook.com, google.co.nz, grubber.co.nz, stackoverflow.com
```

and i would like to check how many times facebook.com shows up in the whole table (in every row)

Comment: You're better off normalizing your database first.

Comment: is it comma separated value? i mean you have columns like this, `ID`, `User` and `Likes` (which is csv)?

Comment: @knittl yer i know, the stucture is crap it's just for a bit of testing

Comment: The problem is that many programs written as a simple prototype end up going into production. It's not a good idea to write bad code even when you're "just testing an idea", because before you know it your bad DB design will end up being the master database and you won't be able to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming every user can only like the same page once, this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE likes REGEXP '[[:<:]]facebook.com[[:>:]]'
```

PS: Normalize your table, you **will** run into serious trouble with a layout like this in the very near future!

Comment: Doesn't that match notfacebook.com too?

Comment: Just normalize! csv fields are almost always a bad idea

Comment: Sure, but that's not the question.

Comment: true... that's why I upvoted. (just emphasis-sing your PS :p)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a lazy fashion, issuing a LIKE SQL query :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table 
WHERE my_table.likes LIKE '%facebook.com%'
```

This is really (REALLY) not cpu friendly. Especially with large tables

Otherwise, you could use MySQL fulltext indexes feature.

You may find more details in [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `like` operator to match the pattern:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS occurences  WHERE likes LIKE "%facebook.com%"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the "LIKE" statement.
It goes like this (if you want to know which user likes facebook.com)

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE likes LIKE '%facebook.com%'
```

Anyway, please consider storing the likes in a 1:n table construct and not as a string

By that you have a a table storing all like-able sites, a user table and a user-likes table storing the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(likes) from yourTable where likes like '%facebook.com%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option. Get the row data in a variable and then use the function preg_match_all (http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php).

This function returns the number of occurrences of the regular expression passed in the first parameter.